# Email picture attachments as inline along with the email body

Tags: scripting, email, perl, mutt

I'm right now working with a script for emailing attachment (.png pics). Since I'm using `mutt` command with `-a` option, the email is sent as a mail attachment.

I want these .png pictures to be mailed inline with the mail body. How can I implement this with a bash script?

I had also tried with the `mail` command and the result was the same. Also I would like to have any ideas on this if it can be done with a Perl script.

Comment: What do you mean by “inline”? An attachment is what happens when you send more than one piece of data in an e-mail, e.g. some text and a picture. Is the body text? HTML?

Comment: Term inline was used here because currenlty when I sent this email with .png picture attachments ,for all email client ,it would require to download all my .png picture to view them.what I really need is pictures to be present along with email body so that when someone open the email,he could see the pic displayed without downloading .(These png pictures are all server monitoring graphs)

Answer (score 2):

By default mutt will label all non-text attachments and images as Content-Disposition: attachment - You can change this setting using Content-Disposition: inline

Set your .muttrc like this:

```
set attach_format="%u%D%I %t%4n %T%.40d%> [%.7m/%.10M, %.6e%?C?, %C?, %s] "
```

(%I is for inline , the other options are document in the manual : http://linux.die.net/man/5/muttrc )

Alternatively, this Perl script might help you :

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
 use strict;
 use Mail::Sender;

 my $sender;

 ref ($sender = new Mail::Sender({from => 'you@xxxxxxxxxxx',
                                  smtp => 'your.smtp.server'})) 
        or die "$Mail::Sender::Error\n";

 ref ($sender->MailFile({to =>'address@xxxxxxxxxx',
                         msg=>"Here's your daily image\r\n\r\n", 
                         subject => 'Daily image',
                         file => 'image.gif',
                         disposition => 'inline'}))
        or die "$Mail::Sender::Error\n";
```